# How to start on this ER diagram homework?

Tags: erd

Please help me to solve this homework. I need to draw the ER diagram, relationships and cardinality.

> An environmental Agency needs to catalog all the plants in an area that is vulnerable to acid rains. Plants exist in quadrants and a botanist is responsible for cataloging plants. The data that should be stored should include genus,species,quantity (in numbers,kg's) of the plants, date of record, quadrant id, quadrant location, average altitude of quadrant and botanists information such as name.

Comment: Sorry but this question is off topic here, check out the [guidelines for what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). To get this question into a state where it is on-topic you need to edit it to have a more succinct question about something in particular, asking how to implement a whole project is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin to learn how to draw an ER diagram, you will do well to learn the differences between a relational model of the data and an ER model of the data.  Most of the ER diagrams being presented here in SO are really diagrams of a relational model.

This may seem overly picky, but the confusion between the two kinds of models slows down beginners enormously.  If you have decided on a relational model, and want to use an ERD to depict it, you can do that.  But learn how to make a model before you learn how to draw a picture of a model.